# How to stop object going under another object?

Tags: modeling

I am new to blender and am trying to put these eggs into the "Carton". I am obviously scaling them down later, but for some reason, all the eggs go BEHIND the carton and I cant put them on TOP of it. How would I do this? Please be as simplistic as you possible can, I have absolutely no idea what im doing!
Thanks[image]

Comment: If you are just starting with blender please read through the resources on this page: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: Can you please upload your blend file using a file sharing site like dropbox.com, and post the link here? The problem could be any number of things at this point, and it would be much easier to look at it than to guess.

Comment: @Bjtatty: all objects can intersect (thankfully, or you could not use booleans) but there are ways to do this: you could use snapping, or you could make blender "simulate" object collisions, and let you get what you want: in this case I would try rigid bodies, but there are also other ways, probably. If you're new to blender, you have just to start with the basics as someone said above, you will get there... but I suggest to practice with something simpler before.